# 12.04 indicates filesystem check on next boot, but never does one

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, fsck

Just installed 12.04 32 bit on my machine, with 3 drives. When I open a terminal window or ssh in remotely, I see:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686)                                   

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/                                                           

*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***                                           
*** /dev/sda2 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***                                           
*** /dev/sdg1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***                                           

Last login: Fri Aug 31 08:15:41 2012 from ....
```

However, if I reboot, I never see it doing a disk check on boot up, like I used to see with 10.10.  Note, after install, I was not seeing the grub menu on boot. I made a ISO disk with BootRepair and now I get the normal grub menu.

Any idea as to why the disk check is not happening on boot (I know I can boot a Live CD and then check the disk - I just want the check on boot working)?